# auto send file via skype using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, skype

I am creating a utility program to automatically send a backup files via skype in vb.net. I have found a code:

skype.Client.OpenFileTransferDialog("skypeidtosend", "D:\Backup\")

But it will open dialog box first and you need to select the file you to send, what I want is to send the file without opening dialog box. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim DataObject As New DataObject
Dim file As String = "<path to file>"
DataObject.SetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, True, file)
My.Computer.Clipboard.SetDataObject(DataObject)
SkypeClient.Client.OpenMessageDialog(UserToSendTo)
SkypeClient.Client.Focus()
SendKeys.Send("^(V){ENTER}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I already solve, I used this codes:

```
 refSkype.Client.OpenMessageDialog(UserToSenTo)
 refSkype.Client.Focus()
 SendKeys.Send("+^(F)PathOfFileYouWantToSend%(O)")
```

Using SendKeys.Send to send the shorcut SHIFT+CTRL+F and put the path of the file, then pressing ALT+O to execute.. :)